# Plot data with different confidence intervals

Tags: plotting

I want to plot something like the graph in the figure.

[image: grapgh]

I have some points (data) and each of them is associated to two different confidence intervals, at 90% (red) and 95% (blue). These intervals can be asymmetric, as you see in the picture.

I tried to use `ErrorListPlot` but I don't manage to plot only the x-errors and the results is a mess.

Comment: Please add data to work with and show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
```

`ErrorBar` accepts two arguments:

```
plot0 = ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[0.3, 0]}}]
```

[image]

which each can be in form of a `List` to indicate assymetric confidence intervals:

```
plot1 = ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[{-0.5, 0.1}, 0]}}]
```

[image]

```
plot2 = ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[{-0.7, 0.3}, 0]}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

You can then just `Show` two plots together (mind the order):

```
Show[plot2, plot1]
```

[image]

or with a more appealing look by introducing an offset ([credit: Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64083/22013)):

```
Show[plot1 /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {x, y + 0.03}, 
     plot2 /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> {x, y - 0.03}]
```

[image]

---

As far as I know, `ErrorListPlot` isn't very flexible when it comes to styling the points and bars separately (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42169/22013) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77868/22013) for custom implementations). I'd combine it simply with a `ListPlot`:

```
plot1 = ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[{-0.5, 0.1}, 0]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0]]
plot2 = ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 1}, ErrorBar[{-0.7, 0.3}, 0]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0]}]

Show[plot2, plot1, 
 ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}]]
```

[image]